# Subtract ith value of a vector from non zero values of the ith row of a sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, sparse-matrix

I want to subtract ith value of the vector from non zero values of the ith row of a sparse matrix for e.g.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    4    0
[2,]    0    5    0    3
[3,]    1    2    0    0
```

and here is the vector that i am trying to subtract:

```
[1] 1 2 3
```

so what i need in the end is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    3    0
[2,]    0    3    0    1
[3,]   -2   -1    0    0
```

I have tried this using apply but haven't been able to figure the problem out, it does not return me quite what i want. The dimensions of the matrix are too large and I do not want to use loops. Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since subtracting a vector from a matrix is performed column-wise, `mat-vec` does the necessary subtraction. Since you only want to use this when the original matrix was non-zero (and return 0 for the elements that were originally 0), you could multiply by `mat != 0`, which is a 1/0 (TRUE/FALSE) matrix stating whether the original element was non-zero.

```
(mat - vec) * (mat != 0)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    3    0
# [2,]    0    3    0    1
# [3,]   -2   -1    0    0
```

If you instead wanted to do it for a sparse matrix:

```
library(Matrix)
(mat <- sparseMatrix(i=c(3, 2, 3, 1, 2), j=c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4), x=c(1, 5, 2, 4, 3)))
# 3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
# [1,] . . 4 .
# [2,] . 5 . 3
# [3,] 1 2 . .
vec <- c(1, 2, 3)
mat@x <- mat@x - vec[mat@i+1]
mat
# 3 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"              
# [1,]  .  . 3 .
# [2,]  .  3 . 1
# [3,] -2 -1 . .
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, although since i m doing this computation on a very large sparse matrix i get a notification: Note: method with signature ‘Matrix#lsparseMatrix’ chosen for function ‘*’,
 target signature ‘dgeMatrix#lgCMatrix’.
 "dMatrix#lMatrix" would also be valid